# Weird connection message from websocket to WinSock

Tags: javascript, c++, websocket, winsock

Edit: I am now getting the messages as I wanted when I set `CONNMSG` size to `[0]`. This way, I don't see http header anymore. 
[Image with Correct messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYVVW.png)

---

I have a c++ desktop software which I will consider as a `server` because my browser side software wouldn't make any sense without it. I am using `WinSock` to send messages to the `/localhost:1111` and can read that message with a c++ client instance.

Now when I initialize the c++ server, and connect to same host (localhost:1111) with websocket client, I will get the following messages on server console:

Image without my message
[image: Image without my message]

In the above case my connection message size is set to 1024 and my message to the client is **not appearing**.
If I set it to 256 like below, the formation of message is spoiled and **my message is squeezed somewhere inside it** like in the image below:

Image with my message
[image: Image with my message]

I'm not sure if I'm supposed to share server side code or client side code. But I think the problem is in the code below:

```
char serverMessage[128] = "MY MESSAGE";
if (newConnection == 0)
{
    std::cout << "Failed to accept the client's connection." << std::endl;
}
else //If client connection properly accepted
{
    char CONNMSG[1024];
    while(true){
        recv(newConnection, CONNMSG,sizeof(CONNMSG),NULL);
        send(newConnection, serverMessage, sizeof(serverMessage), NULL);
        std::cout<< CONNMSG<<std::endl;
        if(!newConnection){
            std::cout<<"Client Disconnected"<<std::endl;
            break;
        }
        Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understand question correctly WinSock is working but websocket is not working right?

Comment: @RushikeshDeshpande I suppose they are both working, because when I connect my websocket server to the port, server starts to ping. And the message from server comes back to the server from websocket client. I'm really confused.